# C++ search filenames pointer to string strcmp error

Tags: c++

I am trying to search for filenames inside a folder so this is the code I reached and it worked perfectly when I used normal text string "file.txt" inside **`strcmp`** but when I changed the string to **`{to_string(ticketid) + ".txt"}`** it didn't work and it started showing to me this error

> "no matching function for call to strcmp"

**This is the code that was working:**

```
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    if ((dir = opendir ("added/"))) {
        while ((ent = readdir (dir))) {
            if(strcmp (ent->d_name, "file.txt")==0)
                flag++;
        }
        closedir (dir);
    }
```

and then when I tried to test this code it didnt work

```
       DIR *dir;
        struct dirent *ent;
        if ((dir = opendir ("added/"))) {
            while ((ent = readdir (dir))) {
                if(strcmp (ent->d_name, to_string(ticketid) + ".txt")==0)
                    flag++;
            }
            closedir (dir);
        }
```

can anyone help me on how to do the second code work as the filename is linked with the ticket id which is an **"int"**

Comment: Don't use the str* functions (like strcmp) in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strcmp` is for "C strings", not for C++ `std::string`s.

It's simpler than you think:

```
if (ent->d_name == to_string(ticketid) + ".txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

You were able to use the "*file.txt*" as an argument because it is a string literal of type `const char[]` that decays to `const char*` which is what the function expects. The `to_string(ticketid) + ".txt"` expression is of type `std::string` and can't be supplied to the `strcmp` function. If you want to keep the `strcmp` function simply utilize the strings [.c_str()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) member function:

```
if(strcmp(ent->d_name, (to_string(ticketid) + ".txt").c_str()) == 0)
```

That being said you should prefer [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) to character arrays.